# Nginx 404 issue when serving static files of a sub-directory

Tags: nginx

I have 404 error when trying to access CSS and JS files of the **sub** static directory. I tried to use **=**, or **~** but it still does not work.

mydomain/sub/index.html **is** served.

mydomain/sub/css/style.css **is not** served.

Here is the Nginx configuration file :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com example.com;

  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  # Global
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  charset utf-8;

  # Logs
  ...

  # SSL
  ...

  # OCSP Stapling
  ...

  # HSTS
  ....

  # Robots
  location /robots.txt {
    return 200 "User-agent: *\nAllow: /";
  }

  # Sub
  location /sub {
    alias /www/sub;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  # Page Speed
  include /etc/nginx/pagespeed.conf;

  # Set expiration policy
  location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|woff)$ {
    expires 7d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";

    proxy_pass http://example;
  }

  # Location
  location / {
    if ($request_method = POST) {
      return 500;
    }

    proxy_pass http://mydomain;
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

in my case, sub directory should use sub location, wish help you.

```
    location /company/default/static/ {
        alias /data/pro/static_deployment/ ; 
        autoindex off; 
        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg)$ {
            expires 7d; 
        }
    }
```